# Unable to Push deployment from Travis ci to cloudcontrol

Tags: travis-ci, cloudcontrol

Unable to Push deployment from Github repository to CloudClontrol using Travis CI, Below is the log:

```
Deploying application
Warning: Permanently added 'cloudcontrolled.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
To ssh://xxx.git
! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://awesomeblog@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

Is there a way to force hard push overriding the status of remote git?

In case you need to see full logs, you can find it here https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/26330194/log.txt. Note that the relevant log is at the end.

Comment: Well, have you done a git pull as requested?

Comment: two repositories are in a very different state, would doing a pull be dangerous?  Also, I had similar situations while deploying to Heroku and Openshift, where git state of heroku/Openshift was completely different than the state of my github repo, but still it was able to deploy the code with Hard push

Comment: There is reciprocity in play: if a pull is dangerous, so is a push. I can't really see how it could be any other way.

Comment: I would manually push once to cloud control with your current code with `git push -f` and then travis-ci should be able to push again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this problem solved with new feature released by Travis CI,

they have added -f option while doing a push during deploy.

All you need to do is add

```
edge: true
```

option for Cloudcontrol deployment as described here http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Other-Providers , in your yml file